# Reliably align images correctly?

Tags: css

I have a list of images shown on a site as a list:

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="1.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="2.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="3.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="4.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="5.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="6.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="7.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="8.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

It could be a variety of heights, but the widths are always the same. In other words, you will always find alignments:

```
X X X X
X X X X
```

or

```
X X X
X X X 
X X
```

But currently they are aligned at the 'bottom' so that each image's bottom part, is align with the following images's part. What I want is for all images to appear in the center. I.e. Not this:

[image: not this]

but rather this:

[image]

How can I reliably align these, so that this alignment is always possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle`:

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CHs5/)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
li{
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```